# copy constructor

Tags: c++, copy, binary-search-tree, nodes

I am working with a binary search tree. Here I'm writing a function to delete an item from the tree. In the following code:

```
if(root = NULL)//if there is nothing in the tree
{
    cout<<"the Tree is empty"<<endl;//ouput to the screen
    return;//exit the function
}

bool isFound = false;//tells us if the item is found
Node* tmp = new Node();//declare a temp pointer
Node* tmp2 = new Node();;//declare a temp pointer
tmp* = *root;//assign the pointer to something
```

It is calling the copy constructor, but as I have it right now I'm just copying the values like this:

```
Node& Node::operator= (const Node& node)
{
    data = node.data;
    left = node.left;
    right = node.right;
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: What's the actual question?

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning pointers, to assign the objects you need

```
*tmp = *root;
```

`tmp` and `root` are of type `Node*`; `*tmp` and `*root` are of type `Node`.

Comment: will i need to write a copy constructor then?

Comment: @TravisLeonSorensen are you managing resources? Is ownership of the resources defined? (It's not a questions I can answer only with that information)

Comment: @TravisLeonSorensen better read - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three

Comment: okay so when i add that it goes to the copy constructor. will i need to just copy everything from the root to tmp? and what do you mean by resources?

Comment: @TravisLeonSorensen as I said, it's not something that can be answered in a comment box - read the question and answers in the link I provided & try to understand them.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(root = NULL)
```

change it to

```
if(root == NULL)
```

it is also wrong:

```
tmp* = *root;//assign the pointer to something
```